How do I increase the timeout for my Vercel Flask Python app serverless function?
So, I have a serverless function that is running Python Flask, but I get hit with the FUNCTION_INVOCATION_TIMEOUT, and I don't know how to increase the timeout. My code is stored in App.py, but I am not sure what to write in the vercel.json file. I appreciate Help.
Can't really find a solution.
